# PHP clean RSS populated by WYSIWYG editor in CMS

Tags: php, rss, wysiwyg

So I have an RSS feed created by a list of blogs. every now and again someone using the WYSIWYG editor in the CMS puts in some random character and it makes the feed invalid.

I have forced UTF8 encoding, and been doing string replace on the chars that slip through, but I wondered is there a nice quick and easy RSS cleaning / sanitising function that would always return valid RSS no matter what was put in?

**Edit:** Also a solution without using frameworks such as PEAR / Zend would be ideal :)

Comment: You could try http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Beautifier/

Comment: ideally something framework free (ie no zend, pear, etc) if poss? :)

Comment: Are you sure all data is UTF-8 encoded at all stages (frontend, backend & database)? If so, there should be no 'random characters'. Look at the database definition, data manipulation in PHP and HTTP encoding. Use Multibyte String PHP functions because the default String functions don't handle UTF-8 correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of characters are you talking about here? Will PHP's built in htmlspecialchars() function do what you want?

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: I already use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php and still some manage to get through